# I want to create a DFS database to store some basic information, which has no clear time partition field. How to implement it in dolphindb?

Tags: dolphindb

I want to create a DFS database to store some basic information, which has no clear time partition field. How to implement it in dolphindb?
I look up in the development maunal, function  createPartitionedTable() must give a clear partition schema.

```
 createPartitionedTable(dbHandle, table, tableName, [partitionColumns])
```

Is there a convenient way to create no Partitioned DFS table?

Comment: Since dolphindb is specifically a time series database (according to the tag), I'm suprised there is "no clear time partition field" in your data. The first example on this page https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?database.html shows you how to create a non-parititoned database.

Comment: Reading the docs... the partition doesn't need to be a time field.

Comment: Lastly... you could use `createTable` instead of `createPartitionedTable`. All this I learnt from the docs I just read